# Paging when using Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using GraphServiceClient to access the Graph API. I'm not sure how to handle paging though. Let's say I run the following query which will return more than 100 records (and hence page):

```
var users = await client.Users
    .GetAsync(rc => { 
        rc.QueryParameters.Select = new[] 
        {
            "userPrincipalName", "displayName", "id" 
        };
    });
```

In the results response I can see the OdataNextLink property, but I'm not sure how to use it. Can anyone give an example? All the documentation I've found seems to be based on using Graph Explorer or direct HTTP requests.

Comment: and you can also take a look at [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/paging?tabs=csharp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `PageIterator`. `PageIterator` has property `State` which indicates whether the iteration has started or whether is completed.

In `CreatePageIterator` you can specify callback action. Add the current user to a list of users.

Until `pageIterator.State` is not `Complete` you need to call `pageIterator.IterateAsync()` to return data from next page.

Each invoke of `pageIterator.IterateAsync()` will return users for the current page.

```
var response = await client.Users
            .GetAsync(rc => {
                rc.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "userPrincipalName", "displayName", "id" };
            });

var userlist = new List<User>();
var pageIterator = PageIterator<User, UserCollectionResponse>.CreatePageIterator(client, response, (user) =>
{
    userlist.Add(user);
    return true;
});

await pageIterator.IterateAsync();
```

The documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#pageiterator) (only simple example)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. Also thanks for the documentation link, I've been looking for something like that for a while!

Comment: The documentation just does `IterateAyns()` while do do loop. So which is it? Do I need to keep checking the state? If so - why is that missing from documentatioN?

Comment: @macwier Good point. No need to have 'while' loop. Answer updated.